# Podman rootless containers communication issue

Tags: mariadb, podman

I am trying to run a test Wordpress blog using rootless Podman conteiners.

I tried many variations of those tutorials:

https://www.linuxwave.info/2020/12/installing-wordpress-using-podman.html

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/podman-vs-docker-deploying-wordpress-application-kritik-sachdeva

It always ends up in Wordpress communicate (displayed on website, not CLI) `Error establishing a database connection`.

I am working on VPS / Ubuntu 22.04. Let me show you what my configuration looks like:

```
podman pod create --name myblog --publish 8080:80

podman run --detach --pod myblog \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=mywpdb \
-e MYSQL_USER=mywpuser \
-e MYSQL_PASSWORD=1234 \
--name mywpdb docker.io/library/mysql:8

podman run --detach --pod myblog \
-e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mywpdb:3306 \
-e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=mywpdb \
-e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=mywpuser \
-e WORDPRESS_DB_PASWORD=1234 \
--name mywp docker.io/library/wordpress:6.0
```

Containers are up and running

```
ubuntu@vps:~$ podman ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                            COMMAND               CREATED        STATUS            PORTS                 NAMES
17bc532160f2  k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.5                                   6 minutes ago  Up 5 minutes ago  0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp  6118c5649aee-infra
186ee1f374db  docker.io/library/mysql:8        mysqld                5 minutes ago  Up 5 minutes ago  0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp  mywpdb
1ad7071a46a6  docker.io/library/wordpress:6.0  apache2-foregroun...  5 minutes ago  Up 5 minutes ago  0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp  mywp
```

Pod looks ok:

```
ubuntu@vps:~$ podman pod inspect myblog
{
     "Id": "6118c5649aeedb8666b1eeba40679787c1bfa25c33438424191a497b81e823bf",
     "Name": "myblog",
     "Created": "2022-11-11T20:27:54.388753429Z",
     "CreateCommand": [
          "podman",
          "pod",
          "create",
          "--name",
          "myblog",
          "--publish",
          "8080:80"
     ],
     "State": "Running",
     "Hostname": "",
     "CreateCgroup": true,
     "CgroupParent": "user.slice",
     "CgroupPath": "user.slice/user-libpod_pod_6118c5649aeedb8666b1eeba40679787c1bfa25c33438424191a497b81e823bf.slice",
     "CreateInfra": true,
     "InfraContainerID": "17bc532160f255750cac00a47e4e2c3cc2597104867ca73d3ff9fc57b896399e",
     "InfraConfig": {
          "PortBindings": {
               "80/tcp": [
     {
          "HostIp": "",
          "HostPort": "8080"
     }
]
          },
          "HostNetwork": true,
          "StaticIP": "",
          "StaticMAC": "",
          "NoManageResolvConf": false,
          "DNSServer": null,
          "DNSSearch": null,
          "DNSOption": null,
          "NoManageHosts": false,
          "HostAdd": null,
          "Networks": null,
          "NetworkOptions": null,
          "pid_ns": "private",
          "userns": "host"
     },
     "SharedNamespaces": [
          "ipc",
          "net",
          "uts"
     ],
     "NumContainers": 3,
     "Containers": [
          {
               "Id": "17bc532160f255750cac00a47e4e2c3cc2597104867ca73d3ff9fc57b896399e",
               "Name": "6118c5649aee-infra",
               "State": "running"
          },
          {
               "Id": "186ee1f374dbf052e0da25cce674cd5fc96a6609744ff004455079f5eeeb5e29",
               "Name": "mywpdb",
               "State": "running"
          },
          {
               "Id": "1ad7071a46a6106900d93269ff94df0fdd8ffc848df74891b1bb0cdeda1cb266",
               "Name": "mywp",
               "State": "running"
          }
     ]
}
```

Mysql is running

```
ubuntu@vps:~$ podman logs mywpdb
2022-11-11T20:28:28.722895Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.31'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I think there is a problem with communication between wordpress container and mysql container, but I failed to debug it, trying many try-hard solutions. Please hint me how to debug this issue.

**EDIT:**

I managed to connect but access is denied:
I used idea from podman networking tutorial

```
podman run --detach \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE='mywpdb' \
-e MYSQL_USER='mywpuser' \
-e MYSQL_PASSWORD='1234' \
-p 6969:3306 \
--name mywpdb \
docker.io/library/mariadb:10


podman run --detach \
-e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST='12.12.12.12:6969' \
-e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME='mywpdb' \
-e WORDPRESS_DB_USER='mywpuser' \
-e WORDPRESS_DB_PASWORD='1234' \
-e WORDPRESS_DEBUG=1 \
-p 8080:80 \
--name mywp \
docker.io/library/wordpress:6.0
```

Now it ends up in mariadb refusing the connection.

```
2022-11-11 21:50:29 9 [Warning] Access denied for user 'mywpuser'@'10.0.2.100' (using password: YES)
```

I have to further investigate this

Comment: `MYSQL_*` and `MARADB_*` env variable are only applied if the database is initializing and not on a restart if the database is already installed on .

Comment: @danblack I think this is not a problem here, since my workflow consists of 'podman run ...' and if it fails I use 'podman rm -f ...' to delete database and wordpress containers. Btw I will try to use rootfull containers as security is not a priority in this newbie deployment

Comment: WORDPRESS_DB_PASWORD you missed an "S". Correct: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original attempt with putting them in a pod contained a couple of small mistakes.

Here is the diff against a working version.

```
12c12
< -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mywpdb:3306 \
---
> -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 \
15c15
< -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASWORD=1234 \
---
> -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=1234 \
```

Firstly - containers in a pod all share the localhost address, so you can use that for the host. Note - "localhost" is used to mean the unix socket with mysql rather than actual networking, you want the IP address.

Secondly you missed an "S" from the variable setting your password.

Do that, and if it doesn't work straight away do `podman pod restart myblog`.